# How do I include object in DataGrid or SimpleForm in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

How do I render an object with another object in it? E.g. I have a user object which has a field baseProfile which all look like this:

- User

  - Id: String
  - Name: String
  - Address: String
  - BaseProfile:

    - password: String
    - email: String
    - ......

---

I can easily use a SimpleForm or DataGrid to show or edit the first layer of data, how to show or edit the child object?

Answer (score 2):

All inputs and field accept a path with dots.

```
<TextInput type="password" source="BaseProfile.password" />
<TextInput type="email" source="BaseProfile.email" />
```